# CURSOR not looping more than once

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005, cursor

I am new to SQL Server stored procedures ... I have written a code which is not looping correctly I believe ...

Note: I am unable to use a Debugger so to debug I have used PRINT commands (old school style)

I am using SQL Server 2005

Code enters into the loop and PRINTs the lines only once - where else their are 29 Totals records to be looped and worked on

```
PRINT 'check if rows are their or not for Adjusting X flags records Results 5 '

SELECT 
    td_clientcd , td_scripcd, cm_name, td_scripnm, 
    sum(td_bqty) td_qty,
    sum(td_sqty) td_sqty, 
    sum(td_bqty-td_sqty) net 
FROM 
    ##VX, Client_master with (nolock)  
WHERE
    td_clientcd = cm_cd  
    AND td_clientcd = @client_cd 
GROUP BY 
    td_clientcd, cm_name, td_scripcd, td_scripnm 
HAVING
    sum(td_bqty - td_sqty) <> 0 
ORDER BY 
    td_clientcd , td_scripcd  

DECLARE dataX_Cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT  td_clientcd , td_scripcd,cm_name,td_scripnm, sum(td_bqty) td_bqty ,sum(td_sqty) td_sqty, sum(td_bqty-td_sqty) net FROM ##VX,Client_master with (nolock)  where td_clientcd = cm_cd  and  td_clientcd = @client_cd  group by td_clientcd,cm_name,td_scripcd,td_scripnm having sum(td_bqty - td_sqty) <> 0 ORDER BY td_clientcd , td_scripcd  

    OPEN dataX_Cursor

    PRINT 'i am at 144'
    DECLARE @tempSumQty INT -- has the qty of the Lower Side
    DECLARE @tempHigherSideFlag CHAR -- show which is the Higher side Sell (S) or Buy (B)

    FETCH NEXT FROM dataX_Cursor INTO @td_clientcode, @td_scripcode, @cm_name, @td_scripname, @td_buyqty, @td_sellqty, @net

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        --Example
            -- select * from ##VX where td_clientcd = '26555   ' and td_scripcd = '532804' and td_bsflag = 'B' and td_flag = 'N' order by td_dt desc,td_stlmnt desc
        -- update ##VX set td_flag = 'X' where td_srno = 308
        PRINT 'I am at 155'
        -- !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        if @td_buyqty > @td_sellqty
                BEGIN
            SET @tempSumQty = @td_sellqty -- Sets the sum of Lower side Qty
            SET @tempHigherSideFlag = 'B'
        END
        ELSE
                BEGIN
            SET @tempSumQty = @td_buyqty -- Sets the sum of Lower side Qty
            SET @tempHigherSideFlag = 'S'
        END  -- This will get the higher Side Qty

        PRINT @tempSumQty 
        PRINT @tempHigherSideFlag

        IF @td_buyqty = 0 OR @td_sellqty = 0 -- Just update the flag to X
                        BEGIN
                            -- select a single/multiple records and loop through it and see if 
                            PRINT 'in OR Condition of X flags'
                            DECLARE record_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
                            select * from ##VX where td_clientcd = @td_clientcode and td_scripcd = @td_scripcode and td_bsflag = @tempHigherSideFlag and td_flag = 'N' order by td_dt desc,td_stlmnt desc -- gets the records will needs to be marked X, which are from higher side.

                            OPEN record_Cursor

                            Fetch Next From record_Cursor Into @td_companycode ,@td_stlmnt,@td_clientcd , @td_scripcd, @td_dt, @td_srno, @td_bsflag,@td_bqty, @td_sqty, @td_rate, @td_marketrate,@td_flag,@td_scripnm,@td_desc
                            -- looping
                            While @@Fetch_Status = 0 
                                            BEGIN

                                                -- update the old record with a flag of X 
                                                update ##VX set td_flag = 'X'  where td_srno = @td_srno


                                                -- fetch next
                                                Fetch Next From record_Cursor Into @td_companycode ,@td_stlmnt,@td_clientcd , @td_scripcd, @td_dt, @td_srno, @td_bsflag,@td_bqty, @td_sqty, @td_rate, @td_marketrate,@td_flag,@td_scripnm,@td_desc
                                            END 

                            --Close record_Cursor
                            --Deallocate record_Cursor

            END -- End of Fetch

            -- if need to adjust the records with an insert and a update

            IF @td_buyqty <> 0 AND @td_sellqty <> 0 -- Adjust the record with an insert and update the flag to X
                    BEGIN
                        -- select a single/multiple records and loop through it and see if 
                        PRINT 'in AND Condition of X flags'
                        DECLARE record_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
                        select * from ##VX where td_clientcd = @td_clientcode and td_scripcd = @td_scripcode and td_bsflag = @tempHigherSideFlag and td_flag = 'N' order by td_dt desc,td_stlmnt desc -- gets the records will needs to be marked X, which are from higher side.

                        OPEN record_Cursor

                        Fetch Next From record_Cursor Into @td_companycode ,@td_stlmnt,@td_clientcd , @td_scripcd, @td_dt, @td_srno, @td_bsflag,@td_bqty, @td_sqty, @td_rate, @td_marketrate,@td_flag,@td_scripnm,@td_desc
                        -- looping
                        While @@Fetch_Status = 0 
                        BEGIN
                                                DECLARE @CurrentRowQty INT
                                        --  PRINT 'i am at 198 ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(2), @tempHigherSideFlag )
                                                            IF @tempHigherSideFlag = 'S'
                                                                    BEGIN
                                                                        SET @CurrentRowQty = @td_sqty
                                                                    END
                                                            ELSE IF @tempHigherSideFlag = 'B'
                                                                        BEGIN
                                                                            SET @CurrentRowQty = @td_bqty
                                                                        END

                                                IF @tempSumQty > @CurrentRowQty
                                                                BEGIN 
                                                                    SET @tempSumQty = @tempSumQty - @CurrentRowQty
                                                                END
                                                ELSE
                                                        BEGIN
                                                        --  PRINT 'i am at 213 ' + CONVERT( VARCHAR(2), @tempHigherSideFlag )
                                                            IF @tempHigherSideFlag = 'S'
                                                                    BEGIN
                                                                        SET @td_sqty = @td_sqty - @tempSumQty
                                                                        insert into ##VX select td_companycode ,td_stlmnt,td_clientcd , td_scripcd, td_dt, td_bsflag, td_bqty, @tempSumQty, td_rate, td_marketrate,td_flag,td_scripnm,'' from ##VX where td_srno = @td_srno
                                                                        update ##VX set td_flag = 'X' ,td_sqty = @td_sqty where td_srno = @td_srno

                                                                    END
                                                            ELSE -- IF @tempHigherSideFlag = 'B'
                                                                    BEGIN
                                                                        SET @td_bqty = @td_bqty - @tempSumQty
                                                                        insert into ##VX select td_companycode ,td_stlmnt,td_clientcd , td_scripcd, td_dt, td_bsflag, @tempSumQty, td_sqty, td_rate, td_marketrate,td_flag,td_scripnm,'' from ##VX where td_srno = @td_srno
                                                                        update ##VX set td_flag = 'X' ,td_bqty = @td_bqty where td_srno = @td_srno
                                                                    END 
                                                        END -- end of else
                                -- fetch next
                                Fetch Next From record_Cursor Into @td_companycode ,@td_stlmnt,@td_clientcd , @td_scripcd, @td_dt, @td_srno, @td_bsflag,@td_bqty, @td_sqty, @td_rate, @td_marketrate,@td_flag,@td_scripnm,@td_desc

                            END 
                    --Close record_Cursor
                    --Deallocate record_Cursor  

                        END

                --  FETCH NEXT FROM dataX_Cursor INTO @td_clientcode, @td_scripcode, @cm_name, @td_scripname, @td_buyqty, @td_sellqty, @net

                END -- End of Fetch
```

and finally I

```
Deallocate record_Cursor
Close dataX_Cursor
Deallocate dataX_Cursor
```

Comment: You should **avoid** cursors - and you can, in over 90% of the cases. Don't put effort into making cursors go fast - just **get rid of them** !

Comment: You have a verbose code and 3 nested cursor. simplify your code, remove everything but what you need for looping. only keep print commands. this way you or anyone else will be able to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your `select` returns more than 1 row, right? Try saving @@Fetch_status to 3 different vars like this

```
Declare @dataXStatus Int
Declare @record1_status Int
...
FETCH NEXT FROM dataX_Cursor INTO ... 
SET @dataX_status = @@Fetch_status
WHILE @dataX_status = 0
...
  OPEN record_Cursor
  Fetch Next From record_Cursor INTO ....
  SET @record1_status = @@Fetch_status
  While @record1_status = 0
    ...
    Fetch Next From record_Cursor INTO ...
    SET @record1_status = @@Fetch_status
  end
  ...
  FETCH NEXT FROM dataX_Cursor INTO 
  SET @dataX_status = @@Fetch_status
end
```

and so on... it will become clear to your pretty soon where the error is in your procedure if you have different fetch_status variables for each cursor loop.